# There is a better way to use this Switch func (Swift-Spritekit project)

Tags: swift, switch-statement

```
switch meter {
        case 0...2499:
            bgImage = "backgroundDay"
        case 2500...4999:
            bgImage = "backgroundNight"
        case 5000...7499:
            bgImage = "backgroundDay"
        case 7500...9999:
            bgImage = "backgroundNight1"
        case 10000...12499:
            bgImage = "backgroundDay1"
        case 12500...14999:
            bgImage = "backgroundNight2"
        case 15000...17499:
            bgImage = "backgroundDay2"
        case 17500...19999:
            bgImage = "backgroundNight3"
        case 20000...22499:
            bgImage = "backgroundDay3"
        case 22500...24999:
            bgImage = "backgroundNight4"
        case 25000...27499:
            bgImage = "backgroundDay4"
        case 27500...29999:
            bgImage = "backgroundNight5"
        case 30000...32499:
            bgImage = "backgroundDay5"
        case 32500...34999:
            bgImage = "backgroundNight6"
        case 35000...37499:
            bgImage = "backgroundDay6"
        case 37500...39999:
            bgImage = "backgroundNight7"
        case 40000...42499:
            bgImage = "backgroundDay7"
        case 42500...44999:
            bgImage = "backgroundNight8"
        case 45000...47499:
            bgImage = "backgroundDay8"
        case 47500...49999:
            bgImage = "backgroundNight9"
        case 50000...52499:
            bgImage = "backgroundDay9"
        case 52500...54999:
            bgImage = "backgroundNight10"
        case 55000...57499:
            bgImage = "backgroundDay10"
        case 57500...59999:
            bgImage = "backgroundNight11"
        case 60000...62499:
            bgImage = "backgroundDay11"
        case 62500...64999:
            bgImage = "backgroundNight12"
        case 65000...67499:
            bgImage = "backgroundDay12"
        case 67500...69999:
            bgImage = "backgroundNight13"
        case 70000...72499:
            bgImage = "backgroundDay13"
```

etc... until case 150000

There is a better way to do something like this?
I need to change the background image in the view did load depending on how many meters the player has run so far

Comment: Store the mapping in an external resource (e.g. plist), load it into a dictionary and use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your values are spaced evenly by increments of `2500`.  If `meter` is an `Int`, you could put all of your `String`s in an array and then compute the index:

```
let bgImages = ["backgroundDay", "backgroundNight", "backgroundDay"...]
bgImage = bgImages[meter/2500]
```

---

Approach 2: Take advantage of the repeating nature of your strings and compute them:

```
let index = meter/2500

switch index {
case 0, 2:
    bgImage = "backgroundDay"
case 1:
    bgImage = "backgroundNight"
default:
    let i = index - 1
    if i & 1 == 0 {
        bgImage = "backgroundNight\(i/2)"
    } else {
        bgImage = "backgroundDay\(i/2)"
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a second solution which doesn't require you to list all of your image names in an array because it takes advantage of the regular pattern.